# Show tables from all schemas in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

In Presto

`SHOW SCHEMAS;` returns all schemas

`SHOW TABLES FROM foo;` returns all tables for foo schema

Is there a simple way to return tables from all schemas in Presto?

Comment: I am very new to presto, so go these basic questions: how to restart presto-server, any sample command please. also how to get into presto-shell or presto-cli and get into a database and run a sample select query, thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables;`

Comment: One can also add the `where table_name = 'table_of_interest'` clause to get information on a specific table and it supports the typical Preto fuzzy search as well (i.e., `'%table_of%'`