# Is there any way to display all columns and tables in a schema in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I've been struggling a bit with finding, the tables and columns in a schema in Presto as below in classical PL/SQL: "select column_name, table_name from all_tab_columns?"
In the presto [doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/index.html) didn't found anything pointing to this. 
You can show [columns in a table](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-columns.html) and [tables in a schema](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-tables.html) but not all tables with their respective columns in a schema.
One use case would be for finding a table which contains a desired column name as:
"select column_name, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name like '%something_potentially_useful%'"
A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938321/show-tables-from-all-schemas-in-presto) is answering for how to see all tables and schemas in an information_schema but unfortunately information_schema does not contain column_name as descriptor.

Thank you upfront!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`information_schema.columns` contains all the available information:

```
SELECT * FROM <catalog>.information_schema.columns
```

As of Presto 327, The `information_schema.columns` table has the following columns:

```
presto:default> DESCRIBE tpch.information_schema.columns;
      Column      |  Type   | Extra | Comment
------------------+---------+-------+---------
 table_catalog    | varchar |       |
 table_schema     | varchar |       |
 table_name       | varchar |       |
 column_name      | varchar |       |
 ordinal_position | bigint  |       |
 column_default   | varchar |       |
 is_nullable      | varchar |       |
 data_type        | varchar |       |
 comment          | varchar |       |
 extra_info       | varchar |       |
(10 rows)
```